# Magento UPS Shipping Issue

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've migrated a Magento site from one server to another. I was trying to configure UPS shipping methods, but on new server the shipping methods are not matching. For example, I've disabled a couple of shipping methods, but they still appear in frontend. And also I've disabled the whole ups shipping method and it's still appearing on frontend. Anyone have any idea on how to fix this issue? It works correctly on the original server though. Tried flush magento cache.. no go.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using, respectively on the old and new server?

Comment: Both servers are using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Comment: If you're having this problem after clearing your cache --> Bad file/folder permissions set on your magento installation, var/cache not writable. Your config is being cached in the system tmp folder instead. Clear cache does not clear config cache in system tmp so you have persistent non-changable configuration.

Comment: Hi, I checked. var is set to 775 and cache is set to 777.